# jQuery Font Color Animate On Hover Not Working

Tags: jquery, fonts, colors, jquery-animate, onhover

I am using the following code to attempt to get the font color of my navigation links to animate on hover/off hover. The border bottom color changes correctly but the font color does not. Also it is throwing off my current-menu-item CSS rule for a different color. The desired behavior would be for the font color to go blue on hover and revert to off white off hover, unless it is the current-menu-item which should be font color yellow. I am a novice at this so please excuse my lack of style. I have included the jQuery UI file for color support. Any help is greatly appreciated. Full example can be seen here http://www.buenolisto.com/alma

**JS**

```
        jQuery("li.social").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find("img").stop(true, true).animate({'marginTop': "-=20px"}, 'fast');
    }, function(){
        jQuery(this).find("img").stop(true, true).animate({'marginTop': "+=20px"}, 'fast');
    })
    jQuery("li.reservas").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find("img").stop(true, true).fadeOut({'marginTop': "-=30px"}, 'slow');
    }, function(){
        jQuery(this).find("img").stop(true, true).fadeIn({'marginTop': "+=30px"}, 'slow');
    })
    jQuery('ul.menu li a').hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).stop(true, true).animate({'borderBottomColor': "#2E9ECE",'color': "#FEFEFE"}, 'slow');
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).stop(true, true).animate({'borderBottomColor': "#FFDF85",'color': "#2E9ECE"}, 'fast');
    })
```

Comment: in your code nowhere you are playing with font-color property

Comment: Please can you try and isolate the code that is causing the problem, perhaps in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Some of the jQuery events in your question have nothing to do with the problem (for example the `li.social` event bind is for your social icons and not the menu.

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble I think the `'color': "#2E9ECE"` in the `.animate()` will disagree with you

Comment: @andyb i think op always highlights their problem but color property is overflowed in div

Comment: btw mainly animate function is to animate numeric value http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble Unless you include jQueryUI, which the OP has

Comment: ok! i should not speak nonsense without following op links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer one part about the font colours. The colours are the wrong way around!

`'color':'#2E9ECE'` should be in the first function inside the `.hover()` and `#FEFEFE` should be in the second function.

The full updated code should be:

```
jQuery('ul.menu li a').hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).stop(true, true).animate({borderBottomColor:'#2E9ECE', color:'#2E9ECE'}, 'slow');
    Cufon.refresh(this);
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).stop(true, true).animate({borderBottomColor:'#FFDF85', color:'#FEFEFE'}, 'fast');
    Cufon.refresh(this);
})
```

**Note:** With the `animate({})` syntax, you do not need to quote the properties.

**Edit:** Second part of the question:

To exclude the *currently selected menu item* from the hovering code you can update the jQuery selector to [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) include the list item with the current-menu-item class

```
jQuery('ul li a:not(.current-menu-item)').hover(...)
```

which should fix the second part of your problem.

**Edit 2:** Since you are using [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) to render the fonts, you need to refresh that after setting the using jQuery otherwise it will be rendered in the colour the text was originally (which is white). Adding `Cufon.refresh(this);` to both methods might have some effect but I can't test it since you didn't provide editable source code.

After reading up on this, I don't think Cufon fonts can be animated - see https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/cufon/RFfz6DDY0wU so you should either use [CSS3 fonts](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/), which can be animated or keep the Cufon fonts and simply have the font color change from white to blue on hover, rather than be animated.

Comment: I have take your suggestion and used the code provided, in fact this is how I originally had it. The behavior is still wrong however. Now what happens is the font color does not animate/change (remains off-white) on hover...and it changes to the blue with mouseout off hover. Obviously the current-menu-item piece is a different problem and is still broken...please send site link provided above for an example of the current behavior. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Actually, I don't think the font colour can be animated because it is not a real font. You are using the Cufon fonts which exist (in my browser) as `<canvas>` elements which cannot be animated through jQuery like this. See my update for alternate approaches.

Comment: Andy I appreciate the insight and thank you for looking into this. Can you describe where to insert the cufon refresh statement. I will experiment with this in the morning. Cheers!

Comment: @user1447958 My answer already contains the `Cufon.refresh` command but as I said, I do not think it is possible to animate a Cufon font, so it probably will not make a difference.